# using min with list properly

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
text = input("enter string:")
text.lower()
counta = text.count ("a")
counte = text.count ("e")
counti = text.count ("i")
counto = text.count ("o")
countu = text.count ("u")

if counta > 0:
print ("'a'",counta)

if counte > 0:
print ("'e'",counte)

if counti> 0:
print ("'i'",counti)

if counto > 0:
print ("'o'",counto)

if countu > 0:
print ("'u':",countu)


leastFreq = [counta,counte,counti,counto,countu]
leastFreq.sort()
while 0 in leastFreq: leastFreq.remove(0)
print (leastFreq)
```

task = count vowels in word, print least frequent vowels that occur. in this case, "potato" would print:

```
'a' = 1
'0' = 2
```

how do I make it so that it prints just 'a'? I could use min(leastFreq) but that would only return the value "1". how do I do it so that it prints using the format 'a' = 1 or if there is more than one vowel with the same number of occurences.

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but `text.lower()` doesn't do anything on its own. You need to assign it to something.

Comment: I assume that the indentation errors here are a result of copy/paste into stack overflow's editor?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`min`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min) with an [additional filter condition](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/), testing whether the element is `> 0`:

```
>>> leastFreq = [4, 2, 1, 0, 3, 0]
>>> min(x for x in leastFreq if x > 0)
1
```

But this way, you lose the information what character this count belongs to. Instead of your five different variables, you could create a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesmapping), mapping vowels to their respective counts:

```
>>> text = "potato"
>>> counts = {c: text.count(c) for c in "aeiou"}
>>> counts
{'a': 1, 'i': 0, 'e': 0, 'u': 0, 'o': 2}
>>> counts["o"]
2
```

And then again use `min` with a generator expression and a specific `key` function (to sort by the count, not by the vowel itself).

```
>>> min((c for c in counts if counts[c] > 0), key=counts.get)
'a'
```

If you are interested in the counts of all the letters, you could also use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

Answer (score 0):

A combination of Counter and operator might do the trick:

```
from collections import Counter
import operator
text = raw_input("enter string:")
freq = Counter(i for i in text if i in 'aeiou')
items = sorted(freq.items(),key=operator.itemgetter(1))
min = items[0][1]
for character,frequency in items:
    if frequency == min:
        print character,frequency
```

Answer (score 0):

To minimally change your code:

```
leastFreq = [(counta, 'a'),(counte, 'e'),(counti, 'i'),(counto, 'o'),(countu, 'u')]
leastvowel = min(leastFreq)[1]
```

But you should use `collections.Counter` instead

```
from collections import Counter
text = input("Enter text: ")
c = Counter(character for character in text if character in 'aeiou') #get counts of vowels
least_frequent = c.most_common()[-1]
```

`least_frequent` will then be a tuple like `('a', 1)`

EDIT:  If you want all of the most frequent items you can use `itertools.groupby`

```
lestfreq=list(next(itertools.groupby(c.most_common()[::-1], key=lambda x:x[1]))[1])
```

This looks complicated, but all it's saying is take a list in sorted order and take all the tuples with the same second value and put them in a list.

Comment: neat. this wouldn't capture if two vowels have the same (minimum) frequency though.

Comment: @PrateekDewan good point, see my edit for one possible solution